# Images disappear on hover in firefox due to use of preserve 3d

Tags: css, firefox, sass

this is a sample of what I have made.
https://jsfiddle.net/shrutibansal/sbjp0Leh/

the image is using transformZ property on hover, and the image disappears automatically on hovering sometimes.

I couldn't find  any solution or any alternative with which the same effect can be created

```
 .portfolio {
transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotate(-45deg);
transform-style: preserve-3d;

&--img {
  transition-property: transform;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition-duration: 294ms;
}
:hover {
  transform: translateZ(1.5em);
}
```

}

Comment: Sounds like a Firefox bug

Comment: is there any alternative?

Comment: Tried a couple things such as wrapping the images in `div`s, no idea, sorry

Comment: They don't disappear if you do something else with them on hover such as changing the opacity. And it's not the images fault either - I tried it with two colored divs which also disappear randomly on hover with transform. It's also not the fault of `translateZ` because `scale` `translateY` `rotate` etc. cause the same problem. So it must be `transform` in general. That's all I tested.

Comment: I figured the problem is with preserve-3d in firefox, but couldn't find any other way to do the same animation .